# Database migration in django 1.0.4

Tags: python, django, database, migration

I work on a very old version of django - 1.0.4. Yes, it is to be changed.
My problem is migration in the database, after adding the field: `is_member`

An error occurs:
`no such column: scopes_scope.is_member`

I've been trying to get a command:
`python manage.py syncdb`
That didn't help.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: django didn't have migrations at the time. Add the column manually to your database using raw SQL

Comment: You possibly might be able to get South working with this version of Django.